# Limit Julia memory consumption

Tags: julia, memory-limit

Is there any particular command line flag to use for restricting memory consumption by Julia scripts? (Specifically for Genie apps)

Or any similar way to limit such consumption?

Comment: It's not exactly Julian solution, but while running Julia in docker, you can limit the memory of docker container.

Comment: Related Github issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17987 which mentions "`RLIMIT_AS` can now be used to hard-limit max allocation size", but there seem to be subtleties I'm not clear on, regarding non-Julia libraries.