# Julia - is ulimit working with a Julia session?

Tags: julia, ram, ulimit

I search and it doesn't seem to have a Julia core way to limit RAM used so I search Linux instead.
According [to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44987/406195), I can limit the RAM used by my command to 64GB with:

```
ulimit -v 64000000
```

I am wondering if I do:

```
$ulimit -v 64000000
$julia
$julia>
```

Am I doing everything alright, i.e., everything I do like launching a JuMP model within my Julia console will be limited to 64GB of RAM?

Comment: Related (unanswered question): https://stackoverflow.com/q/61773531/8127 Also, related Github issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17987 which mentions "`RLIMIT_AS` can now be used to hard-limit max allocation size", but there seem to be subtleties I'm not clear on, regarding non-Julia libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ulimit` appears to set resource limits for your *entire user account*, I can find no reason why this should not also apply to Julia processes run under that user account.

The one exception that comes to mind might be if you are running Julia processes on multiple nodes of a linux cluster with, e.g. the Distributed.jl stdlib, but this is a rather niche case.